# Adding additional functions when dragging/dropping file path into NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop

Thanks for the help.

NSTextField already supports what I need it to do: dragging a folder into it returns the folder's path, like this:

/Users/Me/Desktop/New folder

I want other stuff to happen upon completion of the drop. As a basic example - upon completion of the drop into a textField, a second textField returns "Path Accepted"

```
[statusTextField setStringValue:@"Path Accepted"];
```

How is this done?

Again thanks for the assistance.

Paul